# Statistical terminology: "hazard ratio" or "hazards ratio"

Tags: terminology, hazard

I have a question related to statistical terminology. More specifically, about the **hazard ratio**.

When describing the ratio between two hazard rates, we use the term "hazard ratio".

The term "hazard***s*** ratio" is also used, however, less frequently. While the latter seems more correct (hazards in the plural, since a ratio is between multiple instances), the former seems to be used more extensively.

Both terms have been used in literature since the 1980s. For example: hazard ratio (Biometrika, 1981; DOI: 10.2307/2335811) and hazards ratio (Biometrics, 1985; DOI: 10.2307/2530659)

**Question**

What is the correct term: "*hazard ratio*" or "*hazards ratio*"?

Comment: "*Hazard ratio*" is pretty clearly more common, while as far as I can see *hazards ratio* is quite rare; whether you regard it as correct (I do) or not, *hazard* is the clear convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we form a compound noun in English by concatenating two nouns (there are other ways) then the usual practice is for the fist to be a singular noun. The related terms *risk ratio*, *odds ratio* are examples (odds is a singular of course). We even have examples where the first noun only seems to occur in the singular in compounds like *trouser press*.

So, having said that, I would regard *hazard ratio* as the standard form and would think anyone using *hazards ratio* was trying to make some specific point by doing so.